# How to insert comment next to each data point in Google chart

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

Hi
I am using Google chart API (with php) in my project to show some chart like line, pie, bar etc.
I want to insert a comment next to each data point on a chart that's 
created, so that this data can store to the database.

Eg: I have a trend line for 5 years. The values being 10,13,22,15,14 
For one or more of these points, I want to insert a comment in the 
graph that I create. Eg: The spike in Year3 has been due to blah 
blah.... 
How do I do this? 
Any tweaks? 
Please help!!!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

LOOK ON Dynamic Icon Markers,

in http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/chart_params.html

Comment: Hi Haim, Thanks for your reply. I have already gone through the above link but i am not able to find the solution of the above issue. I would like to more clarify about my problem. I want to put an event handler such that, after clicking(mouse) to a data point in chart, it should show a text area as popup or overlay, where user can put there comment related to corresponding data point. After this this comment should be insert into the database. Please give me some idea about this. I am also looking to the Google Interactive chart for this. Thanks in advance!!!